# What is causing the "No Request object configured. Cannot invoke action" error?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i'm trying to upload videos on my youtube account using CakePHP, i tried in simple PHP and it is working fine but, When i converted code into CakePHP it is showing me an error, please help me to figure out.

> Erro is : No Request object configured. Cannot invoke action

Following is the UploadController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
/**
 *
 */
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_YouTube;
use Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet;
use Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus;
use Google_Service_YouTube_Video;
use Google_Http_MediaFileUpload;
use Google_Exception;

/**
 *
 */

 /**
  *
  */
 class UploadController extends AppController
 {

     private $access_token;
     private $OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID;
     private $OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET;

     public function __construct ($access_token)
     {
         $this->access_token = $access_token;
         $this->OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID =
         'replace here';
         $this->OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'replace here';
     }


    public function index()
     {
         if($this->request->is('post')){

         $title = $this->request->getData('title');
         $video = $this->request->getData('video');
         $path =  $this->request->getData('path');
         $description = $this->request->getData('description');

         $results = [];

         if(empty($title)){
             $this->Flash->error('Title cant be empty');
         }else{
             if(empty($video)){
                 $this->Flash->error('Please select a video');
             }
         }
                $results = $this->upload($title, $video, $path, $description);
            }

            $this->set(compact('title','video','path','description'));
     }


     /**
   * @param $video_file : name of the video file to be uploaded
   * @param $file_path : path directory of video file to be uploaded
   * @return bool
   */

   public function test($video_path, $video_file)
   {
       $full_path = Configure::read('video.upload.video.path') . $video_path . DS . $video_file;
       if($full_path){
           return $full_path;
       }
       return $this->access_token;
   }


   /**
     * @param $file
     * @param $path
     * @param $title
     * @param $description
     * @return mixed
     */

     public function upload($title, $video, $path, $description){

         $videoPath = WWW_ROOT . '../'. $path . $video;

         if(!file_exists($videoPath)){
             $response['status'] = 'false';
             $response['message'] = 'Video does not Exists';

             return $response;
         }

         $client = new Google_Client();

         $client->setClientID($this->OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
         $client->setClientSecret($this->OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
         $client->setAccessToken($this->access_token);

         $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

         try{
        // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
        $videoPath = WWW_ROOT . '../' . $path . $video;

        // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
        // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
        // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
        // video category.
        $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
        $snippet->setTitle($title);
        $snippet->setDescription($description);


        // Numeric video category. See
        // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
        $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

        // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
        // "private" and "unlisted".
        $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
        $status->privacyStatus = "private";

        // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
        $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
        $video->setSnippet($snippet);
        $video->setStatus($status);

        // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
        // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
        // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
        $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
        // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
        $client->setDefer(true);

        // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
        $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

        // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
            $client,
            $insertRequest,
            'video/*',
            null,
            true,
            $chunkSizeBytes
        );
        $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


        // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
        $status = false;
        $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
        while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
          $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
          $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
        }

        fclose($handle);

        // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
        $client->setDefer(false);


    }catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
            $response['status'] = false;
            $response_message = json_decode($e->getMessage());
            //debug($response_message);
            $response['message'] = $response_message->error->errors[0]->message;

        } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
            $response['status'] = false;
           $response_message = json_decode($e->getMessage());
           $response['message'] = $response_message->error->errors[0]->message;

        }

      }
     }
```

Following is the index.ctp

```
<?php

?>

<div class="user form large-12 medium-12 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create(null,['type'=>'post']) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Upload Video')?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('title',[
                'value'=> isset($_GET['title']) ? $_GET['title'] : '',
            ]);

            echo $this->Form->input('video',['type'=>'file'],[
              'value'=> isset($_GET['video']) ? $_GET['video'] : '',
                ]
            );
            echo $this->Form->control('path',[
                'value'=> isset($_GET['path']) ? $_GET['path'] : ''
            ]);

            echo $this->Form->control('description',[
            'value'=> isset($_GET['description']) ? $_GET['description'] : '',
        ]);
         ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Upload')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>

</div>
```

Comment: <?= $this->Form->create(null,['type'=>'file']) ?>

Comment: What? I didn't understand sir.

Comment: If you send any file from form , then file type should be 'file' , you have used 'type'=>'post'.It will be 'type'=>'file'

see doc https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#changing-the-http-method-for-a-form

Comment: Sir, i already tried, having same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to create controllers manually, hence there's no reason to modify the controllers constructor, especially not given that what you're doing there messes up its sigunature and functionality, that is accepting the required request and response objects (hence the "*No Request object configured*" error), and the optional name, event manager and component registry objects.

So, don't touch the constructor, read your token from somewhere else, or maybe inject it via a setter.

Also as already mentioned in the comments by Alimon Karim, the correct `type` option for the form helper is `file`. And do not let users specify arbitrary paths for your file storage, that's a possible path traversal vulnerability.

Last but not least, do not access superglobals like `$_GET` directly with CakePHP, use the request object to retrieve request data, and in case of the form helper, it should be able to do that for you automatically (setting the value of a file input isn't possible btw).

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Options for Form Creation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-form-creation)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Getting form values from the query string](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#getting-form-values-from-the-query-string)**
- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html)**